# Taking my project to its previous state

Tags: tfs

I've a project added to my Team Foundation Server 2010 installation and I've done some code check-ins.

I need to restore the project to the point it was in the last check in, but, when I try to get the lastest version or a specific version, one of the files (File1.cs) I've modified is not checked out.

I realized that File1.cs was not checked-in the last time but I wanna roll back the project to the point it was in the last check-in.

What really does "Get lastest version" and "Get specific version"?

I'm very confused about these two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get specific will get file at the given changeset.  But if that file wasn't changed between the changeset you're at and the changeset you're getting, then this is a no-op.

The easiest way to find the version of the file you want to get is through View History.  Find the changeset you want to get, and select "Get This Version".  This will get *only* the file in question at that version.